# Rails: group by the count of a column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

I'm not sure how to best express this question.

Let's say I have a `UserSkill`, which `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :skill`. I have a collection of `Skill`s, and from those I have an array of `skill_ids`, say with `.map(&:id)`.

I can easily use this array to do an `IN` type query like `UserSkill.where(skill_id: skill_ids)`.

But I want to find the users that have the most skills from my input.

I tried writing this naively as `UserSkill.where(skill_id: skill_ids).group("user_skills.user_id").order("count(user_skills.user_id) desc")`, but that has a syntax error.

To further clarify, let's say we have `User id: 1` and `User id: 2`. Our result from `UserSkill.where(skill_id: skill_ids)` is the following:

- `UserSkill user_id: 1, skill_id: 1`
- `UserSkill user_id: 1, skill_id: 2`
- `UserSkill user_id: 2, skill_id: 2`

The result I'd be looking for would be:

- `User id: 1`
- `User id: 2`

What's the right query for this? And how should I be phrasing this question to begin with?

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: @JohnNaegle PostgreSQL

Comment: I might be close! `UserSkill.where(skill_id: skill_ids).select("user_id, count(skill_id) AS skill_count").group("user_id").order("skill_count desc")` seems to maybe be working?

Comment: That actually doesn't return back an array of users, but does at least give me IDs to work with.

Comment: Any way you implement this, you might want a secondary order so you get results in a consistent order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a has_many association from `User` to `UserSkill`, you could try

```
User.joins(:user_skills).
  group("users.id").
  order("COUNT(users.id) DESC").
  merge(UserSkill.where(skill_id: skill_ids))
```

Comment: This looks like it works and is better than my answer in using rails constructs.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL I might write this:

```
select users.*
from users
  join user_skills on users.id = user_skills.user_id
where 
  user_skills.skill id in (1,2,3)
group by users.id
order by count(*) desc, users.id asc
limit 5
```

Which might look like this:

```
User.joins("user_skills on users.id = user_skills.user_id").
     where("user_skills.skill_id" => skill_ids).
     group("users.id").
     order("count(*) desc").
     limit(5)
```

Comment: Appreciate you getting to this answer first! As you said, though, @rossta's answer is nice because of using Arel syntax.